# Is there any function which checks a mathematical expression and returns a valid number in SQL server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have the below code where im using ISnumeric function to check the validity of an expression to do the math in sql.

But if I use ISnumeric function here it returns 0 for both the two conditons listed below. I need some function or a method to identify a valid mathematical expression.

Is there any alternative for this one ?

```
Begin
DECLARE @rcnt as VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @ncnt as VARCHAR(100)
--Condition1
SET @rcnt = '(5918800.000 / 4963400.000) * (Slaughter(1023))'
--Condition2
SET @ncnt = '(5997200.000 / 5059900.000) * (400000.000)'

Select ISNUMERIC(@rcnt) as validittcheck
Select ISNUMERIC(@ncnt ) as validittcheck

END
```

Comment: No, there's nothing built in that does anything like that.

Comment: `select isNumeric(exec('Select ' + @ncnt)) as Validittcheck` may work... but I think you'd need to wrap it in a try catch as the slaughter will fail unless that's a function your code.  In essence, we try it out if it returns numeric you know its' valid, if it returns error you know its not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ISNUMERIC() is a check that a variable is a valid numeric datatype, not that the result of the evaluation of a string expression is a valid numeric value. Your values became non-numeric as soon as the first '(' was evaluated.

The only way I know to get the desired result is to use dynamic sql. Here is an example, notice I put the try catch in there because your Slaughter() function does not exist and an exception is raised, so return zero as it is not a number:

```
DECLARE @rcnt as NVARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @ncnt as NVARCHAR(100)
--Condition1
SET @rcnt =  'SELECT @Result=ISNUMERIC( (5918800.000 / 4963400.000) * (Slaughter(1023)) )'
--Condition2
SET @ncnt = 'SELECT @Result=ISNUMERIC( (5997200.000 / 5059900.000) * (400000.000) )'

DECLARE @ResultValue1 INT=0
DECLARE @ResultValue2 INT=0
DECLARE @ResultParam NVARCHAR(100)= '@Result int OUTPUT'

BEGIN TRY
EXEC sp_executesql @rcnt, @ResultParam, @Result=@ResultValue1 OUTPUT
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
END CATCH

BEGIN TRY
EXEC sp_executesql @ncnt, @ResultParam, @Result=@ResultValue2 OUTPUT
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
END CATCH

SELECT @ResultValue1
SELECT @ResultValue2
```

Comment: Added an alternative.

Comment: You should probaably add some sort of health warning, as this is of course a SQL injection avenue if the source of the values is untrusted.

Comment: Well yes, of course it is. He had his code in a being end block so I assumed it was contained within a stored procedure where the values would be sent in as sanitized parameters. I hope so anyway :) Also, I will point out the empty try catch is useless and a horrible practice. I was just getting his code to execute. I would advise against this kind of query if you can send in your values as parameters it would be cleaner, more efficient and safer...all together a better approach.